# cordova add platform add/build windows8 error

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, windows-8, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am unable to create a cordova/sencha touch windows8 project. When adding platform `windows8` via `cordova platform add windows8` it gives me this error:

```
E:\testAndroid1\<app name>\platforms>cordova platform add windows8
Checking windows8 requirements...
Creating windows8 project...
Creating Cordova Windows 8 Project:
        App Name : -------
        Namespace : com.****.-------
        Path : E:\testAndroid1\<project name>\platforms\windows8
Project created
Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory
    at Object.fs.readSync (fs.js:487:19)
    at Object.fs.readSync (C:\Users\dshahid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cor
dova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfill
s.js:218:23)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:326:28)
    at C:\Users\dshahid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\co
rdova-lib\src\cordova\metadata\windows8_parser.js:325:30
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Object.module.exports.add_bom (C:\Users\dshahid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_
modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\metadata\windows8_parser.js
:319:15)
    at C:\Users\dshahid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\co
rdova-lib\src\cordova\metadata\windows8_parser.js:298:18
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\dshahid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\nod
e_modules\q\q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\dshahid\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modu
les\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\dshahid\AppData\Roaming\npm\nod
e_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:760:13)
```

The steps I am following are:

1. `sencha app refresh`
2. `sencha app build testing`
3. copy all files from /build/testing/ to wwww folder of `cordova` project.
4. Run `platform add windows8` gives error.

Adding wp8 and android work fine and build and run as expected, the issue is only with `windows8`.
Google didn't help either. Please tell what is going wrong.

Comment: no reply? Plz guys i urgently want to get to the problem.

Comment: I finally re-installed windows ultimate version of windows 8.1 and installed visual studio express edition. Previously i had windows professional. don't know what was the problem but reinstalling these things fixed my problem.Thanks for your answers really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally re-installed windows ultimate version of windows 8.1 and installed visual studio express edition. Previously i had windows professional. don't know what was the problem but reinstalling these things fixed my problem.Thanks for your answers really appreciated!

Comment: This is not an answer, post it as comment not as answer.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I tracked it down to a folder in my `bower_components`.

basically you have folder that matches this regex `/\.(js|html|css|json)/`
and because of that `windows_parser.js` tries to read it as a file and explodes.

Comment: where is this bower_components folder, i have searched whole computer but unable to find that.Can you please write the actual path.Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As explained by danyal, I found that one of my folders (which happens to be Chart.js) contains ".js" that matches the pattern `/\.(js|html|css|json)/`.  In my case it was under bower_components, but might be any where in your project as well.

Simply, in the build process of windows8 platform, cordova uses a script called `windows_parser.js` under:

> %AppData%\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\metadata

The script contains the following starting at line 267

```
    ...
    var files = shell.ls('-R', www);

    files.forEach(function (file) {
        if (!file.match(/\.(js|html|css|json)/)) {
            return;
    }

    var filePath = path.join(www, file);
    var content = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
    ...
```

This script tries to enumerate all files, and then matches with ".js, .html, .css, and .json".  It wrongly expects all returned listings are of type file, and then tries to read the content of these files.  If you have a file that contains .js in its name, the script will try to read it and it fails with the error: "Error: EISDIR, illegal operation on a directory".

In short, make sure you don't have a directory under www what could potentially match the pattern above.

-AQ